What is the name of the grammatical function of "there" in "there is"?
Is there a name for the grammatical function of the word "there" in constructions where it is used to denote presence/existence, e.g., "There is an apple on the counter."

Your example is an existential construction in which "there" is a dummy pronoun functioning as subject of the clause.

@BillJ this seems more of an answer than a comment

In English-specific grammars you'll see the term "existential there", but more generally in linguistic theory it is referred to as an expletive or dummy subject. These terms also cover examples like "it" in "It's raining".
In syntax, the idea is that these expletives are terms which some languages have in order to fulfill the requirement for sentences to always have an overt subject.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In English it's usually called "existential 'there'", for example in the Penn Treebank  part-of-speech tagset where it is "EX".

More specifically, "there" is a dummy pronoun functioning as subject of the clause.

@BillJ unlike the dummy it, I would not call there a pronoun; it is not used as a pronoun in any other context, so this justifies IMHO to give it as special status as "existential there".

There is no doubt that existential "there" is a pronoun, particularly as its function is that of subject. It is also significant that "there" occurs as subject in interrogative tags, as in "There is an apple on the counter, isn't there?" Only pronouns are admissible in a tag like that. This means that we know that it's a pronoun.

@BillJ If it “there” is the subject then what is “apple” in “There is an apple on the counter.” and why does the verb agree with “apples” in “There are apples on the counter.”?

@AdamBittlingmayer Not sure on the second question, but on the first, "apple" is the object in that example.

Answering the second question may help answer the first correctly.

@AdamBittlingmayer "Apple" may be analysed as a 'displaced subject'': functionally, it is complement of "be". Regarding agreement, "there" is an unusual kind of subject; it has no inherent number but takes on the number of the displaced subject. It's comparable to the relative pronouns "which" and "who", which take on the number of their antecedent.

@Idran No: in There is an apple on the counter, "apple" is not object but complement of the verb. Regarding  There are apples on the counter, see my last comment to Adam.

@BillJ: I believe in English this is sometimes referred to as a "predicate nominative," although in practice you will more often hear that phrase in connection with sentences like "It is I." (as opposed to "It is me.").

@Kevin I wouldn't say that. "Apple" is a complement of "be", but it's not a predicative complement (your 'predicate nominative'). Predicatives relate to the subject (or object), but "there" is a dummy subject, and therefore cannot be the predicand for a predicative.

@Kevin To put it another way: your 'predicate nominative' (aka predicative complement) analysis won't work because it assumes that “there” here is referential. But it isn’t: this is the dummy “there” found in existential clauses. It is simply a marker of a grammatical construction, serving to fill the subject position.


There is an apple on the counter.

This is an existential clause where "there" is a dummy pronoun functioning as subject.
"There" is simply the marker of a grammatical construction, serving to fill the subject position. We know it's a pronoun because it functions only as subject or raised object, and can fill the subject position in interrogative tags: There is an an apple on the counter, isn't there?
"Apple" may be analysed as a 'displaced subject'; functionally, it is complement of "be".
Regarding agreement, "there" is an unusual kind of subject; it has no inherent number but takes on the number of the displaced subject. It's comparable to the relative pronouns "which" and "who", which take on the number of their antecedent:

There are apples on the counter.

